# How to keep original date format after manipulation?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a reference date like this :

> 2018-05-23T17:02:59+02:00

I need to substract 1 (milli)second from this reference date, then return it on the exact same format, like this :

> 2018-05-23T17:02:58+02:00

I succeeded going to the previous second of the same date like this :

```
var refTime = '2018-05-23T17:02:59+02:00';
var d = new Date(refTime);
var nd = d.setMilliseconds(-1);
```

But I can't find how to output `nd` on the exact same format as `refTime`.

How could I do ?

Comment: use `moment.js`, that plugin will definitely help

Comment: does `var nd = new Date(d.setMilliseconds(-1));` help ?

Comment: In your example you're subtracting a second, not a millisecond. Your date format's resolution is 1 second, i.e. you can't operate on milliseconds level.

Comment: @alx : This is not a problem. I just need to go to the previous second.

Comment: @Taki. I think It helps. I need to try if I can ouput on the same format with this.

Comment: You need to format a timestamp using specific timezone, but in browser `Date` object is limited to either UTC/GMT or to system timezone. So, without using 3rd-party library you need to implement rather complex logic to handle timezones -- quite a task, actually, can't be done in few lines of code and (as many date-related things) very error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Just substract 1 to the date.

```
// 1ms difference
d.getMilliseconds() // 999  
newdate2.getMilliseconds() // 998
```

```js
var refTime = '2018-05-23T17:02:59+02:00';
var d = new Date(refTime);
var nd = d.setMilliseconds(-1);

// new date 
var newdate = new Date(d - 1);
console.log(newdate);
```

Comment: Running the code snippet in site outputs "2018-05-23T15:02:58.999Z" for me, not  "2018-05-23T17:02:58+02:00"

Comment: in `02:58` the 58 refers to seconds

Comment: I think its a snippet bug, try it in your browser console.

Comment: As @Shefeto mentionned, this is not the ouput I'm looking after.
Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Get second and set subtracting a second
var refTime = '2018-05-23T17:02:59+02:00';
var d = new Date(refTime);
var nd = d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() - 1);
console.log(new Date(nd))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Using moment js
var refTime = '2018-05-23T17:02:59+02:00';
var d = new moment(refTime);
var nd = d.subtract(1, 'seconds')
console.log(new moment(nd))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```